# How to find the perfect matching?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

If $G(A,B,E)$ is a simple , connected bipartite graph with $n$ vertices in both of its vertex classes, and if we let the degrees in one class be different. How can we show that $G$ contains a perfect matching?

What I know from this information:

That $G$ has no loops so we can apply the first Gallai theorem : 
$\alpha + \tau = 2n$ (applied to this case).
Also, since it is a bipartite we can use Konig's theorem : $\nu = \tau$ and $\alpha = \rho$ .

And if I am right the question basically asks either to show that $\nu = n$ 
or I need to show that $|A| = |B|$ and prove Hall's theorem for this $G$.

Now, my main question here is how can I apply Hall's theorem here to show that this graph $G(A,B,E)$ contains a matching covering $A$ or $B$?

I am not sure how can I show that $\forall x \subsetneq A :|N(x)| \leq |x|$ here.(Hall's theorem; $N$ refers to the neighborhood)

Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can procede inductively. Since all vertices say in $A$ have different degrees and it is connected, then we have in $A$ vertex $v$ with degree $1$. Say it is connected with $u$ in $B$. Now repeat everything in $A'=A\setminus \{v\}$ (and $B'=B\setminus\{u\}$).

You can see that vertices in $A'$ have again different degrees ($u$ was connected to all vertices in $A$, othervise $G$ would not be connected graph).

Answer (score 0):

Such a graph may not have a perfect matching.  A counterexample is:

[image]

This graph has a cherry (two degree-$1$ vertices with the same neighbor) and thus does not admit a perfect matching.

Comment: But in your graph you have vertices with the same degree on both side.

Comment: My interpretation of “...we let the degrees in one class be different...” is that it does not assert they’re all distinct, just that we allow the possibility that they’re different (as opposed the usual situation where Hall’s Theorem is used, which are k-regular).